# Decide custom post types, taxonomies for a Wordpress website

Tags: wordpress, plugins, custom-post-type, custom-taxonomy

I am planning to create one website in Wordpress. That **website is about Player's competitions**. A player will compete against another player i.e. a match.

I am planning to **display each player's details, upcoming matches, match records**

I am confused about how to use pages, custom post types, taxonomies.

**Can anyone help me to decide, what should be custom post type, custom taxonomy? Which plugin should I use?**

**I am confused about how to show upcoming match between Two players!**

Comment: Using wordpress core register_post_type in a custom plugin or https://wordpress.org/plugins/custom-post-type-ui/ can help you generate your post types. Advanced custom fields is a great plugin for adding fields to post types including relationships between post types. You can then use a 'Match' custom post type to display information about the match. You can then use WP_Query to get Matches where there is a relationship between a match and the currently logged in user or a particular user. A plugin like ultimate member to get you started with user profile pages.

Comment: Yah you are right but do you have any idea, what should I use to display UPCOMING  match  information  between two players?? Means taxonomy or new custom post type??

Comment: Custom post type for Matches would give you more flexibility to extend it later in the long run. Using the relationship field from advanced custom fields you could select the players (http://www.advancedcustomfields.com/resources/relationship/) and you could follow this tutorial to use that relationship field to show the players on the Match page: http://www.advancedcustomfields.com/resources/querying-relationship-fields/ . Sorting and filtering by date in a WP_Query can allow you to display upcoming matches: https://codex.wordpress.org/Class_Reference/WP_Query#Date_Parameters

Comment: Ok .. Thank you vey much for your help.. so I will create one custom post type for players and other for Matches..